# chart alignment in plotly bar chart

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart

my title alignment is not working left in chart. how to align title left.

I am trying to align title left in my graph below but not working for me please help what am i missing here or which line i have to update

```
df <- data.frame("LOC" =c("CA","NY","WA","TX"),
                 "TAX" = c(3421.00,5640.00,7880.32,4569.00))

ttl ="Tax collection"

g <- plot_ly(df, x =~TAX, y = ~ LOC, type = 'bar',width = 1200, height =900, showlegend=F
             , text = ~paste0(roundUp(TAX*100), "%"), textposition = "outside",
             marker = list(color = "blue"))


tit <- list(
  text = ttl,
  font = cht_ttl,
  xref = "paper",
  yref = "paper",
  xanchor = "right",
  x = 0.1,
  y = 1,
  showarrow = FALSE
)
ax <- list(
  title = "",
  showgrid = FALSE,
  range = c(0, 1)
)

chart <- g %>% layout(annotations = tit,
                      xaxis = ax,
                      yaxis = list (title = " "),font=chrt_title, showline = TRUE)

chart
```

Comment: Please include the non-base packages that you are using. Which package is `roundUp` function from?

Comment: roundup is customized rounding, just updated

Comment: @RonakShah so in my example Tx collection should at top left but it coming above the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xanchor = 'left'` with `x` value less than 0.

```
library(plotly)

tit <- list(
  text = ttl,
  font = chrt_title,
  xref = "paper",
  yref = "paper",
  xanchor = "left",
  x = -0.04,
  y = 1,
  showarrow = FALSE
)


chart <- g %>% layout(annotations = tit,
                      xaxis = ax,
                      yaxis = list (title = " "),
                      font=chrt_title, showline = TRUE)

chart
```

[image]

Comment: this i am getting already in my code , so tax collections should be aligned top left,  above WA legent , its coming above bar chart now

Comment: The title is already at top left. I don't understand where you want it to be ?

Comment: You can adjust the `x` value. I have updated the answer to show how it looks with `x = -0.04`. You can reduce that further as per your need.